# creating a link to youtube channel on angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to link my youtube channel with my angular app.

I have tried the following and am getting the error:

Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.

my page.ts file is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { YoutubeService } from './youtube.service'
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
selector: 'app-coachingtips',
templateUrl: './coachingtips.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./coachingtips.page.scss'],
})
export class CoachingtipsPage implements OnInit {
videos: any[];
unsubscribe$: Observable<any>;

constructor(private youTubeService: YoutubeService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.videos = [];
this.youTubeService
.getVideosForChanel('MY-CHANNEL-ID', 3)
.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
.subscribe(lista => {
for (let element of lista["items"]) {
this.videos.push(element)
}
});
}}
```

my youtube.service.ts file is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YoutubeService {

apiKey : string = 'MY-API-KEY';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

getVideosForChanel(channel, maxResults): Observable<Object> {
let url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=' + this.apiKey + '&channelId='   
+ channel + '&order=date&part=snippet &type=video,id&maxResults=' + maxResults
return this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(map((res) => {
    return res;
  }))
}}
```

if there is anything you can recommend I would hugely grateful? many thanks

console.log(this.videos)

[image]

Comment: can you show the results of `console.log(this.videos)` ?

Comment: thanks Michael, have added a pic of the console.log. is this what you were after?

Comment: yes so its totally empty, does the rest api returns anything ?

Comment: sorry new to this, if i do the web address https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key= + apiKey it returns this:   "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "QOyiAc_b-Cm8Roon3itMxH1MaH0",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "GB",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 5

Comment: can you show the results of `console.log(lista)` because i dont see any property `items` in the rest api response

Comment: thanks, sorry I am not sure how to add the console.log to the (lista) in the code above without causing issues? i do wonder where he (followed this guide https://kheronn-machado.medium.com/youtube-angular-en-2ed98f07e0f9) got the items property from!

Comment: .subscribe(lista => {console.log(lista)...}

Comment: thanks Michael, nothing appears in the console log, just the empty array from before.

Comment: so the `subscribe` method is never called ?

Comment: no i don't think the subscribe method is being called

Comment: where the `getVideosForChanel` method is called ?

Comment: sorry not sure I understand fully, i think the getVideoForChannel method is called in the youtube.service.ts file above? no?

Comment: oh yes sorry my bad: can you test this: `.subscribe(lista => {..}, (error) => console.log(error))` and see if any errors are printed in the console

Comment: thanks, that comes back with an error saying "declaration or statement expected", however it runs if I remove the 2 dots so run .subscribe(lista => {}, etc but again nothing appears in console log, sorry this is not proving easy! thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)`, http subscriptions are automatically removed when component is destroyed and this is what cause you trouble.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-coachingtips',
templateUrl: './coachingtips.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./coachingtips.page.scss'],
})
export class CoachingtipsPage implements OnInit {
  videos: any[];
  constructor(private youTubeService: YoutubeService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.videos = [];
    this.youTubeService.getVideosForChanel('MY-CHANNEL-ID', 3)
    .subscribe(lista => {
      for (let element of lista["items"]) {
        this.videos.push(element)
        }
    });
  }
}
```

It should work better, now you should have a 400 http error: `API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key`. So with valid api key it should be ok.

I manage to reproduce your problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4xrvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: ah many thanks! IT WORKS! hugely appreciate the help!